# getting error running yarn start-debug-proxy command

Tags: php, hadoop-yarn

I am getting below error while running the `yarn` start-debug-proxy command.

```
yarn start-debug-proxy
yarn run v1.22.4
$ cd src/public/;CURL_DEBUG=${CURL_DEBUG:-1} PORTAL_DEBUG=${PORTAL_DEBUG:-1} php -S ${PORTAL_HOST:-0.0.0.0}:${PORTAL_PORT:-8800}
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
[Sat Apr 25 11:42:25 2020] Failed to listen on ‘0.0.0.0’:8800 (reason: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: please format your error and share more details about your environment